# Marshal.PtrToStructure marshaled string is empty

Tags: c#, marshalling

I'm trying to marshal a struct from a byte[]. Each part works except marshaling a string. It looks to me like a BSTR:

```
06 00 00 00 48 00 65 00 6c 00 6c 00 6f 00 21 00 00 00
```

So, that's a 4-byte length then "Hello!" in unicode with a double null terminator. Here's the marshaling code I have toyed with:

```
string auto = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(nextSchedulePtr); // returns "Hello!"
string ansi = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(nextSchedulePtr); // returns "H"
string uni = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(nextSchedulePtr);   // returns "Hello!"
string bstr = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(nextSchedulePtr); // returns "Hel"
Schedule schedule = (Schedule)Marshal.PtrToStructure(nextSchedulePtr, typeof(Schedule)); // returns "" with UnmanagedType.BStr and UnmanagedType.LPWStr
```

Method 1 calls method 3 anyway, so this makes sense. However, I can't specify any type within the [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.X)] attribute that will allow the structure to return anything meaningful whatsoever.

I have pared down the structure to this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct Schedule 
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string Name;
}
```

I've literally tried all of the valid values for UnmanagedType.X and they either throw AccessViolationExceptions or return an empty string or return junk. None returns "Hello!". Am I not able to load this data into a struct?

Note: I cannot change the data, it is set in stone. I can, however, change my code. I have also pinned the byte[] so it is not being GC'ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `Schedule` struct you are defining matches this kind of C struct:

```
struct Schedule {
    BSTR *Name;
};
```

While the structure that exists in memory at the `IntPtr` you are tinkering with has the layout:

```
struct Schedule {
    BSTR Name;
};
```

If you use `Marshal.StructureToPtr()` on an instance of `Schedule` and then inspect the memory, you will see that only the first four bytes get set, because they are a pointer.

Unfortunately, there is no elegant workaround to this in .NET.  You cannot use a non-pointer string in a struct because then the struct would be of variable length.

If it is an option, forgo the struct entirely and stick with `Marshal.PtrToStringAuto()`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now that I think about it. Thank you. Annoying, but at least there's a workaround that I can abstract away from client code.

Comment: Yeh, interop with unmanaged code can suck. At least you're dealing with P/Invoke and not JNI...